# How do I match groups from Exchange Online to Azure AD?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server

I want to uniquely identify a group that is used in Exchange Online so that I can find the same group in Azure AD. The group has, in my case, permissions on a mailbox as returned by `Get-MailboxPermission` in PowerShell.

When using the `Get-Group` cmdlet from the *ExchangePowerShell*-Module I get a few identifying properties, but none of those are helpful in identifying the same group in Azure AD:

- DisplayName (not unique and changeable)
- SamAccountName (not available via Graph API or AzureAD PowerShell module)
- Sid (specific to Exchange Online and not the same as in Azure AD)
- WindowsEmailAddress (changeable, not required)
- ExchangeObjectId (not available via Graph API or AzureAD PowerShell module)

In Azure AD I have a whole other set of identifying properties (e.g. Graph API):

- ID (the ObjectID displayed in Azure AD, not available in Exchange Online)
- DisplayName (not unique and changeable)
- Mail (changeable, not required)
- SecurityIdentifier (specific to Azure AD and not the same as in Exchange Online)

It seems my only option would be to use a combination of DisplayName and maybe WindowsEmailAddress/Mail which is horrible?

Is there any other way I could uniquely identify the groups to match them together?

**UPDATE:**
My scenario is as follows:
I need to process all permissions of all mailboxes:

1. I basically call `Get-MailboxPermission` for every mailbox.
2. By expanding the property User I can get the Exchange-SID of the permitted user or group.
3. I can then match this Exchange-SID to a user or group as returned by the `Get-User` or `Get-Mailbox` cmdlets.
4. I can find the corresponding Azure AD user by matching the `ExternalDirectoryObjectId` as returned by `Get-User`.
5. The group does not have the property `ExternalDirectoryObjectId` and no other uniquely identifying and unchangable property that can be found in Azure AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1 : Matching the Group ID From Graph API to Exchange Online Commandlets**

Getting the list of the groups from the Graph and matching it with the group from the Exchange Online Commandlets.

The Id Obtained from the Graph API will match that of the Get-Group

The below is the snippet of the Graph response :

```
{
            "id": "c0749057-8163-4228-be88-1a0df3aab7b1",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "classification": null,
            "createdDateTime": "2020-09-08T11:21:53Z",
            "creationOptions": [],
            "description": "This is a new Group",
            "displayName": "NewGroup1",
            "expirationDateTime": null..............
```

If you get the Id : c0749057-8163-4228-be88-1a0df3aab7b1 & Run the below command, you will get the corresponding group :

```
Get-Group -Identity "c0749057-8163-4228-be88-1a0df3aab7b1"
```

**Output :**

[image]

**Case 2 : Matching the Group ID from the Exchange Online Commandlets to Graph Group ID**

(**UPDATE**)

Only the unified groups will be visible in the Graph APIs (or) will have the ExternalDirectoryObjectId

So you could run

```
(Get-UnifiedGroup -Identity <Your Exchange Group ID>).ExternalDirectoryObjectId
```

This will return the Azure AD Object Id of the Group.

[image]

HTH !

Comment: @manuel I have updated my answer for the reverse scenario. Pls check and let me know

Comment: Thank you very much for your definitely helpful answer! I have clarified my use case in my original question.

That would mean I would have to make single calls to Get-Group for every Azure AD group that can be used for mailbox permissions. Since that is rather inefficient and probably slow or prone to throttling I want to ask: Is there no other way? :-)

Case 2 does not really apply since the groups can easily be mail-enabled security groups and can thus not be found by Get-UnifiedGroup.

Comment: @Manuel - I had done a quick check on the commandlets Unfortunately, as far i've researched, i dont see an alternate way. –

Comment: Thank you! An inefficient way is better than no way :-).